# How do you use custom views in Eclipse Android development?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, view

I have downloaded a custom view and I want to implement it in my project but here's my dilemma: People use big terms or imply an action that I have never done before and have no knowledge of.

This is the view I am trying to download: http://androidcustomviews.com/holocolorpicker/

My questions are:

1. How do I import a view into an existing Eclipse project?
2. Which gradle file do I modify? There are 5 for me (build.gradle, gradle.properties, gradlew.file, gradlew.bat, settings.gradle).
3. Why do you have to add 'compile' to the gradle? Isn't this something the developer could just write in it?

Comment: Don't use eclipse for android development. Official support was dropped like a year ago - use android studio instead

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but *why* are you using still eclipse, especially if you are a beginner?

Comment: It is not a problem,you should read a book or watch video first.

Comment: At rekire @Tim Castelijns, I actually did not know that support was dropped, I learned Java on Eclipse and it had an Android IDE so I figured it would be the same. I do have Android Studio though so I'll start using that, now using Android Studio, how would I accomplish it?

Comment: His using Eclipse because many courses like Slidenerd explaining android in this a bit old-schooled IDE

Comment: @EgosZhang I have read books on Android and I've finished hundreds of tutorials, the issue is that none of them cover how to import _italic_ someone else's views _italic_. There is legit NOTHING about using someone else's views on the first 30+ pages of Google and the README's attached to the files do not say how to do it either.

Comment: @kaio37k for italic you surround the word(s) with * asterisks, like `*this*`

Comment: @piotrek1543 Exactly. MyBringBack, TheNewBoston, Cave of programming, and many Udemy courses use Eclipse for Java and Android.

Comment: @kaio37k but as previous say try to do these courses in Android Studio, not Eclipse ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> How do I import a view into an existing Eclipse project?

It is not so much "importing a view" as it is importing the library that will let you use the view, which is explained below.

> Which gradle file do I modify? There are 5 for me (build.gradle, gradle.properties, gradlew.file, gradlew.bat, settings.gradle).

One of the build.gradle files. One will look somewhat like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0-beta1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

that is not the right one as the comment suggest. You need to add it to the other one, which looks somewhat like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'
}
```

See I added it at the bottom along with the other dependencies.

Now when you do a gradle sync, the library will be downloaded and automatically included in your project.

After that you can use the view in your xml file like any other view

With a regular view you use :

```
<View
  ..
  .. />
```

Now with this custom view you use:

```
<com.larswerkman.holocolorpicker.ColorPicker
  ..
  .. />
```

> Why do you have to add 'compile' to the gradle? Isn't this something the developer could just write in it?

I'm not able to answer that, because it is a choice of the gradle development team. But basically with `compile` you say "here I have this library, please compile it into the project for me"

Comment: So by adding 'compile' to the gradle, Android Studio will automatically install it without having to drag and drop any files?

Comment: @kaio37k yes, well, it's a combination of `compile` and then the 'url' to where gradle can find the library. But indeed you do not have to drag or copy and files yourself

Comment: Will it automatically import the Views to Android Studio as well?

Comment: @kaio37k there is only 1 view, and that is `com.larswerkman.holocolorpicker.ColorPicker`. How you use it in your app is up to you. You need to use it in your xml files wherever you want to use them

Comment: but what I mean is, if I follow the instructions you listed, will the View also work in Android Studio or will it only work in Eclipse?

Comment: @kaio37k it is IDE independent. It only depends on gradle, which is built in android studio, so it will surely work

Comment: The only gradle file in there that has the 'dependencies' method looks like the first file you put, the one that I should not put the compile line into.

    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common     to all sub-projects/modules.
    
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        version = VERSION_NAME
        group = GROUP
    
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

Comment: @kaio37k There is another, it might be in another folder but it has to be there. If it is and the dependency section is missing, you can add it manually, however it should be there as it is added when you create a project

Comment: But how would it know if a project has been created if it hasn't been compiled yet? This is the contents of the View: https://github.com/LarsWerkman/HoloColorPicker

Comment: I do have a file that starts with 'apply plugin: 'com.android.application'', is this the on I should add the depencies line to?

Comment: @kaio37k ehh. Compiling is something that is done after a project has been created (and implemented)

Comment: @kaio37k yes that is the one

Comment: @TimConstelijns I followed those steps exactly and I get the error "The following classes could not be found: - com.larswerkman.holocolorpicker.ColorPicker"

Comment: @kaio37k did you sync gradle?

Comment: @TimConstelijns I synced the gradle and rebuilt the project.

Comment: @kaio37k can it find anything else from the `com.larswerkman.holocolorpicker` package?

Comment: How would I know if it did find anything else? There's only one view. These are the contents of the gradle: apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
 
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'
}

apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'

Comment: In xml type `com.larswerkman.holocolorpicker` and hit ctrl+space, see what the autocomplete gives you

Comment: If I type it as "com.larswerkman.holocolorpicker" it doesn't say anything, if I type it as "<com.larswerkman.holocolorpicker" it says "No Suggestions"

Comment: And was the gradly sync successful?

Comment: It doesn't explicitly say there are any errors if that's what you mean.

Comment: Then there is no indication why it would not work, I cannot help you any further

Comment: Maybe my gradle file dependencies were not placed in the right scope? Could this be a cause?

Comment: @kaio37k when you make a project with android studio it automatically puts them in the right place

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need to add dependency to gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'
}
```

After that, you can use this color picker in your layout, just adding like a simple view.

```
<com.larswerkman.holocolorpicker.ColorPicker
    android:id="@+id/picker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Nicely copy pasted from the docs (that OP linked to which means he probably already read this), but doesn't answer the question(s)